# How to delay between assertions in jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, assertion

I am making a call to DynamoDB to get number of items from it using JDBC connection configuration, JDBC request-before. Than there is http request which creates few items in DynamoDB. This takes from few seconds to a minute. At the end there is again JDBC request and JSR223 assertion.
Any way to make the second JDBC request delayed? Right now the number of items always end up being same being because it is being queued up in DynamoDB and takes time to increase # of items.
I have tried adding constant timer but it delays everything within that thread group.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Timers obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
2. Timers create delay **before** each Sampler in their scope

In order to create the delay before the JDBC Request you need to make time **a child** of the JDBC Request.

Alternatively you can replace it with [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)